# Increase FFT resolution with AnalyserNode

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I think I might be a bit confused using the AnalyserNode. I currently have my userAudio stream "line-in" connected to an AnalyserNode. I then fill up a Uint8Array using `getByteFrequencyData()`.

When I play a single 440Hz tone, the frequency with the highest intensity in my array will either be 468Hz *or* 421Hz (depending on how much I vary it). Is there a way that I can increase the resolution around these frequencies, so that it has more frequencies between 468 and 421Hz?

When I plot the fft data with a 440Hz tone, you can see the two intense frequencies at 468Hz and 421Hz. Is there a way to average out the FFT data into a separate array, so that the intensities of the 468Hz and 421Hz (among other points) data points are averaged? I guess it would be like interpolating the data in between the frequencies...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/puYw3/ (I'm not sure if this actually works because I don't have a microphone on my current computer).

Comment: you could shift the frequency of the signal (using playbackRate or detune) to a lower frequency, then analyse this signal. (maybe some filtering would help).

Comment: What FFT size are you using (if not default 2048)? Could you show some of the code/create a fiddle?

Comment: I'm just using the default 2048. I'll attach a jsfiddle in a moment.

Comment: This may help: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14906/how-to-get-the-10-5-most-dominant-frequency-in-an-audio-signal

Answer (score 1):

The is coming a little late, but maybe someone will find it useful.

You can increase the "resolution" of the fft with the property [fftSize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/fftSize) of AnalyserNode.

Since the fftSize maximum value is limited (I believe something around 2^15 at the time writing this) you will still end up with rather imprecise values. It is possible to increase the precision using [parabolic peak interpolation](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Quadratic_Interpolation_Spectral_Peaks.html)